# latest version of com.tinkerpop.gremlin:gremlin-groovy:jar not present in maven central repo

Tags: maven, groovy, tinkerpop3

latest version of com.tinkerpop.gremlin:gremlin-groovy:jar  not present in maven central repo. last version of the TPL is 2.6.0.  I this TPL moved to different package or license.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.tinkerpop.gremlin/gremlin-groovy/2.6.0

Comment: I don't understand your question because https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.tinkerpop.gremlin there you see a version 2.6.0 ?

Comment: The question is https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:gremlin-groovy. is this related?

Comment: The version 2.6.0 is released in 2014 and this is the latest version I am finding in maven repo. after that there is no release?

Comment: The group was renamed to `org.apache.tinkerpop`

Comment: So Maven Central is the correct location... https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.tinkerpop